# How do I replace the connection string element

Tags: azure-devops, web-config, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an issue I cannot seem to solve using XML Transform. My `web.config` contains the following

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLConnString" 
         connectionString="yada yada" 
         providerName="System.Data.SQLClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

My QA server and above has this

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData>
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
    </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```

What task do I use in DevOps to achieve this kind of transform or what's the best way to go about this kind of transformation.

jc

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the exactly caused you mentioned is what, but you can use [File transform task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) to achieve the above transformation. I have tested it again and it work very fine on my side.

```
steps:
- task: FileTransform@1
  displayName: 'File Transform: '
  inputs:
    folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    enableXmlTransform: true
    xmlTransformationRules: '-transform **\*.Dev.config -xml **\*.config'
    fileType: xml
```

For the rules **syntax** in this task definition, please follow:

```
-transform <path to the transform file> -xml <path to the source file> -result <path to the result file>
```

---

In your scenario, you need also ensure your transform file is configured available. Before run it in azure devops pipeline, you can verify it firstly [here](https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/).

---

**Updated in 2/20/2020:**

Based on your comments, the trouble for you to apply file transform is on transforma file configured. Though you have got the method of powershell, but I also help you written a transform file so that you can have more choice here.

```
<connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Remove">
  <add name="SQLConnString" 
       connectionString="yada yada" 
       providerName="System.Data.SQLClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider" xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <EncryptedData>
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
    </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```

You can see my transformation result:

[image]

Comment: Here is the problem. Transform assumes I am either replacing an element within <connectionStrings> or a token still within that Add element. I need to replace the entire <connectionStrings></connectionStrings> not just the connection string within that element. As it stands now I decided on using power shell. I used the test site. Thanks for that one makes it easy testing out other configs without the RSA problem.

Comment: @RocketMonkey. To let you have more choice in file transform, I helped you written a transform file which can achieve what you want. You can have a try. Just a suggestion of mine:-)

Comment: @RocketMonkey, Hi, how the things going? Does the transform rules I updated is help for you? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing any issues, feel free to leave comment here :-)